# How to change long tap text of the drawer (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a drawer in my
app. When I long tap it, "Open navigator menu" pops up. How can I change this? I already tried changing somethings in `drawer.dart` etc. but it didn't work.
[image: The text which pops up]

Answer (score 0):

it depends which action you use.
if you want different tap behaviour you can user [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

with Default drawer class, use Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); to open drawer with text in GestureDetector.